# Invalid write on a structure

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I am trying to create a polynomial from a group of monomials, with a structure for both. I have an append function which is failing due to an invalid write error, and know I need to allocate space for the new monomial, but am not sure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
typedef struct Monomial {
typede Monomial {
    int coeff;     /* coefficient */
    int exp;       /* exponent    */
    struct Monomial *next;  /* next monomial */
} Mono;

typedef struct Polynomial {
    int   deg;     /* degree */
    Mono* first;   /* first monomial */
    Mono* last;    /* last monomial  */
} Poly;
```

This function creates a new monomial with a given coefficient and power.
  c : the coefficient
  k : the power
  The function allocates a monomial and initializes its attributes.
  The return value is a pointer to the newly created monomial.

```
Mono* newMono( int c, int k) {
  Mono m = {c, k, (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(Mono)) };

  Mono * mp = (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(m));
  return mp;
}
```

This function creates a new (empty) polynomial with degree 0 and no
  monomials.

```
Poly* newPoly() {
   int deg = 0;
   Mono * first = NULL;
   Mono * last = NULL;
   Poly p = {deg, first, last};
   Poly * point= (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(p));
   return point;
}

    }
```

This functions adds a monomial inside a polynomial
  p : the polynomial to modify
  m : the monomial to add
  The polynomial p is expected to be the sole owner of m.
  The new monomial should be added at the end of the list.
  The degree of the monomial should not exceed the degree of the polynomial

```
void appendMono( Poly* p, Mono* m) {
   if((*p).first){
     Mono* l = (*p).last;
     (*l).next = m;  //ERROR IS HERE
     (*p).last = m;
   }
   else {
     (*m).next = (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(Mono));
     (*p).first=m;
     (*p).last=m;

   }

}
```

This function allocates, reads and returns a polynomial.
  It starts by asking the highest degree
  Then it reads all the monomials (which are given in increasing
  order of powers) as pairs of integers (whitespace separated)
  and adds them to the polynomial.
  It finally returns the constructed poly.

```
Poly* readPoly() {
   //TODO
   Poly* p = newPoly;
   int deg;

   int pow, coef;
   scanf("%d", &deg);
   while(scanf("%d %d", &pow, &coef)){
    Mono * m = newMono(pow, coef);
    appendMono(p, m); //ERROR CALLED FROM HERE
   }
   return p;
}
```

Comment: What does this do, other than leak memory? `Mono m = {c, k, (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(Mono)) };` Same with this, although it doesn't leak memory it does go out of scope immediately. `Poly p = {deg, first, last};`

Comment: Same for `Poly * point = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));`

Comment: That was just my attempt to allocate memory. I'm really new to C so I am not sure where I should place a malloc statement

Comment: You must allocate memory after declare the variable and before use it ;)

Comment: Simplify `Mono * mp = (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(m));` --> `Mono * mp = malloc(sizeof *mp); mp->coeff = c; mp->exp = k; mp->next = NULL;`  Drop `Mono m = {c, k, (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(Mono)) };`  `newPoly()` needs re-write too.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but the error wasn't solved

Comment: Side node: don't write `(*l).next` but rather `l->next`. It's exactly the same, but nobody uses the first variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty far away from working code.

This doesn't do what you think:

```
Mono* newMono( int c, int k) {
  Mono m = {c, k, (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(Mono)) };
  Mono * mp = (Mono*)malloc(sizeof(m));
  return mp;
}
```

Malloc returns uninitialized storage, so this function returns junk. It's also useless to cast the return value of `malloc`. Just make sure you have `#include <stdlib.h>` in the program head.

Try this:

```
Mono *newMono(int coeff, int exp) {
  Mono *p = malloc(sizeof *p); // Check for NULL return in production code
  p->coeff = coeff;
  p->exp = exp;
  p->next = NULL;
  return p;
}
```

Follow the same pattern for `newPoly`. You're apparently trying to build an aggregate and then copy it into `malloc`ed memory. That will work, but it's wasteful unless your compiler is smart enough to eliminate the extra copy. Just do it the straightforward way.

To append, there is no need to allocate any new storage.  You're only adjusting pointers.

```
void appendMono(Poly *p, Mono *m) {
  if (p->first) {
    p->last->next = m;
    p->last = m;
  } else {
    p->first = p->last = m;
  }
}
```